# How do one develop an extensible angular.js app?

Tags: angularjs

We would like to develop app that other developers can extend,
different user will have different extension, those extensions are only client side and run where the same app is running(in the browser)

our core app is angular.js

Comment: Check out this blog http://briantford.com/blog/ . Brian gives great hints on building scalable modular angularJS apps

Comment: where is there a legitimate question in this post? Would expect this from someone with 6 reputation points, but not with 1800

Answer (score 1):

Use modules. A lot.

Group every thing that relates into a extra module. These modules could be used from where they are needed. And only modules that are needed need to be injected.

Also. Split all the stuff into smaller files similar to the modules. Use a build system that is intelligent enough to know what you need.

Read [this blog post](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html) from brian ford.